# Conflicts with Yum install php-mysql on Centos7

Tags: php, mysql, linux, centos, centos7

While trying to install php-mysql on a Centos 7 box... a conflict error occurs... I am not an expert CentOs Linux user. Any help is much appreciated with this issue.

```
[root@xweb01 ~]# yum -y install php-mysql

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * epel: epel.mirror.constant.com
 * extras: mirrors.mit.edu
 * ius: ius.mirror.constant.com
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: repos-va.psychz.net

Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 will be installed

--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 for package: php-mysql-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 will be installed

--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 for package: php-pdo-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 will be installed

--> Processing Dependency: libzip.so.2()(64bit) for package: php-common-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libzip.x86_64 0:0.10.1-8.el7 will be installed

--> Processing Conflict: php71u-common-7.1.10-2.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.1.10-2.ius.centos7
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php71u-common.x86_64 0:7.1.10-2.ius.centos7 will be updated

--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.10-2.ius.centos7 for package: mod_php71u-7.1.10-2.ius.centos7.x86_64
---> Package php71u-common.x86_64 0:7.1.16-1.ius.centos7 will be an update

--> Running transaction check
---> Package mod_php71u.x86_64 0:7.1.10-2.ius.centos7 will be updated
---> Package mod_php71u.x86_64 0:7.1.16-1.ius.centos7 will be an update

--> Processing Conflict: php71u-common-7.1.16-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.1.16-1.ius.centos7
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: php71u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64

 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: You're using non-standard PHP packages from IUS to get 7.1, so you want `php71u-mysql`.

Comment: I tried yum -y install php71u-mysql and received the following error: No package php71u-mysql available.

Comment: I tried yum -y install php71u-mysqlnd and it was installed correctly. Not sure why the package name has "nd" in its name. Do you know why?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.